# How to request future items of a list

Tags: tables, checkbox

I have the following problem going on:

(not going into detailed context as it is extremly complex, and also irrelevant to the point)

- in a checkbox table, a user can select which events they want to be transmitted
- they can check all in the table header
- some events may not exist now and still the user would want to include them in the selection
- therefore, I need to have a wildcard option that says: I'm checking all current existing events, and want to check any other that may be listed in the future too

My question here relates exclusively to the UI, so how do you think I could communicate the option to select future events along with all current?

[image]

Comment: What is the maximum number of events that might appear in the list? You're showing 3, could there be 50?

Comment: There could be hundreds of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try adding a persistent (and differentiated) sticky row that allows selection, but also links to an explanation.

Based on what you've shared, it seems you have to have both:

- A way of selecting future events
- The ability to convey this concept

You can distinguish the row in some visual manner (I have a sketch below with a row and text color change), along with an info tip to explain the concept for newer users. I've placed it persistant at the bottom, so the normal selections are dealt with first.

[image]

Comment: Way more elegant than what I was originally imagining, Mike. I think that will work fine. Thank you 

Answer (score 2):

From the comments...

> There could be hundreds of events.

Tweaking [Mike's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/145413/93969)...

Put option to automatically select events that may be added later up next to the "select all events" checkbox:

[image: include future]

...so the option doesn't get lost at the end of long lists of events.

Another reason not to list it with events is because it's not an event—it's a list selection modifier, so group it next to the other list selection modifier.